# Flex and Java GWT integration

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, gwt, blazeds

How to connect `Flex` application to `JAVA GWT`. Some java side data like strings,Image send to edit in flex editor which is a `SWF`, when user complete his editing on the SWF,then edited data return back to the java application.

How can I achieve this?

how can we create a `SWF` that would be able send data to the java application.

Comment: Are you looking for [GWT +FLEX=GWT4FLEX](http://www.devchronicles.com/2011/12/gwt-meets-flex-gwt4flex.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expose your data layer as [RESTful services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) using one of many tools, such as the JAX-RS server [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net) or other of the many toolkits (I am assuming that you have your data services written in Java given the reference to GWS).

Hook up the GWT and Flex to the restful services, eg using [How to access REST service in Actionscript 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180515/how-to-access-rest-service-in-actionscript-3) or for GWT, see [How to call RESTFUL services from GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030969/how-to-call-restful-services-from-gwt)

Then GWT and Flex both operate on the same data layer in a [MVP pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter), where GWT/Flex is VP and the RESTful services are M.

I was involved in several projects that did this to great success.

The following question is also worth reviewing: [Should I build a REST backend for GWT application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906369/should-i-build-a-rest-backend-for-gwt-application)

Comment: have you worked on any open source project? can I see any type of code?

Comment: @dev: I've worked on some open source (see my bio), but none in this area. I have updated the answer with links to some other questions from SO that seem highly relevant.